# Inserting XML Multiple Nested Nodes into SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
 <NIACList>
    <NIAC>
            <Number></Number>
            <SubmissionDate></SubmissionDate>
            <ExpirationDate  />
            <IssuerIDNO></IssuerIDNO>
            <IssuerName></IssuerName>
            <SuspensionPeriod/>
            <Cessation>
              <Basis  />
              <Date  />
            </Cessation>
            <Merchant>
              <IDNx></IDNx>
              <Name></Name>
              <Address>
                <Region></Region>
                <Locality></Locality>
                <Street></Street>
                <House></House>
                <Block  />
                <Flat  />
                <Phone  />
                <Fax  />
                <Email  />
              </Address>
            </Merchant>
            <CommercialUnit>
              <IDNx  />
              <Name  />
              <Type></Type>
              <Area></Area>
              <Location></Location>
              <Address>
                <Region></Region>
                <Locality></Locality>
                <Street></Street>
                <House></House>
                <Block  />
                <Flat  />
              </Address>
              <Activities>
                <Activity>
                  <Code></Code>
                  <Name></Name>
                </Activity>
              </Activities>
              <Goods>
                <Good>
                  <Name></Name>
                </Good>
              </Goods>
              <WorkProgram  />
              <PublicSupplyUnit>
                <Capacity  />
                <TerraceCapacity  />
              </PublicSupplyUnit>
              <TradingAlcohol  />
              <TradingBeer  />
              <TradingTobaccoProducts  />
              <AmbulatoryTrading  />
              <MobileUnitTrading></MobileUnitTrading>
              <MobileUnit>
                <Type  />
                <Length  />
                <Width  />
                <Height  />
              </MobileUnit>
              <CommercialApparatusTrading></CommercialApparatusTrading>
              <CommercialApparatus>
                <Count  />
                <Length  />
                <Width  />
                <Height  />
              </CommercialApparatus>
            </CommercialUnit>
            <Modifications  />
          </NIAC>
    </NIACList>
```

Based on this XML structure I've created in MS SQL a DB with the following script for tables:

```
create table NIAC (
IDNIAC int identity primary key,
Number nvarchar(80) null,
SubmissionDate datetime2 null,
ExpirationDate datetime2 null,
IssuerIDNO  nvarchar(max) null,
IssuerName  nvarchar(60) null,
SuspensionPeriod datetime2 null,
Modifications nvarchar(60) null
);

create table Cessation (
IdCessation int identity primary key,
Basis nvarchar(60) null,
Date date null,
IDNIAC int 
);


create table Merchant (
IdMerchant int identity  primary key,
IDNX nvarchar(max) null,
Name nvarchar(max) null,
WorkProgram datetime2 null,
IdAddress int 
);

create table Address (
IdAddress int identity  primary key,
Region nvarchar(60) null,
Locality nvarchar(50) null,
Street nvarchar (60) null,
House nvarchar (10) null,
Block nvarchar (10) null,
Flat nvarchar(10) null,
Phone nvarchar(30) null,
Fax nvarchar(60) null,
Email nvarchar(60) null

);

create table CommercialUnit (
IDCommercialUt int identity primary key,
IDNx nvarchar(90) null,
Name nvarchar(90) null,
Type nvarchar(90) null,
Area int null,
Location nvarchar(max) null,
TerraceCapacity float null,
TradingAlcohol bit null,
TradingBeer bit null,
TradingTobaccoProducts bit null,
AmbulatoryTrading bit null,
MobileUnitTrading bit null,
CommercialApparatusTrading bit null,
IdAddress int,
IDActivities int ,
IDGoods int ,
IDMobileUnit int ,
IDCommercial int ,
IDPSU int 
);


create table Activities (
IDActivities int identity  primary key,
Code nvarchar (90) null,
Name nvarchar (90) null
);

create table Goods(
IDGoods int identity  primary key,
Name nvarchar(60) null
);

create table MobileUnit(
IDMobileUnit int identity  primary key,
Type numeric null,
Length numeric null,
Width numeric null,
Height numeric null
);

create table CommercialApparatus(
IDCommercial int identity primary key,
Count float null,
Length numeric null,
Width numeric null,
Height numeric null
);


create table PublicSupplyUnit(
IDPSU int identity  primary key,
Capacity float,
TerraceCapacity float 
);


create table NIACList(
ID int identity primary key,
IDNIAC int not null,
IDNIACList int 
);


create table NIACToComponents(
IDNIACToComponents int identity primary key,
IDNIAC int,
IDAddressMerchant int,
IDAddressCU int,
IdCessation int,
IdMerchant int,
IDCommercialUt int,
IDActivities int,
IDGoods int,
IDMobileUnit int,
IDCommercial int,
IDPSU int,

);




drop table if exists NIAC;

drop table if exists NIACList;

drop table if exists Cessation;

drop table if exists Merchant;

drop table if exists Address;

drop table if exists CommercialApparatus;

drop table if exists CommercialUnit;

drop table if exists Goods;

drop table if exists MobileUnit;

drop table if exists  PublicSupplyUnit;

drop table if exists  Activities;

drop table if exists NIACToComponents;



alter table dbo.NIACList
add constraint FK_ID_NIAC 
foreign key (IDNIAC) references dbo.NIAC(IDNIAC)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.Cessation
Add constraint FK_IDNIAC
foreign key(IDNIAC) references dbo.NIAC(IDNIAC)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.Merchant
add constraint FK_IdAdress
foreign key(IdAddress) references dbo.Address(IdAddress)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_IdAddress
foreign key(IdAddress) references dbo.Address(IdAddress)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;


alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_Activities
foreign key(IDActivities) references dbo.Activities(IDActivities)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_IDGoods
foreign key(IDGoods) references dbo.Goods(IDGoods)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_IDMobileUnit
foreign key(IDMobileUnit) references dbo.MobileUnit(IDMobileUnit)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_IDCommercial 
foreign key(IDCommercial) references dbo.CommercialApparatus(IDCommercial)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;

alter table dbo.CommercialUnit
add constraint FK_IDPSU
foreign key(IDPSU) references dbo.PublicSupplyUnit(IDPSU)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;
```

Suppose there are lots of `NIAC` into `NIACList`(50-100 nodes), and i want to insert into them data from my XML File.
I've did the `INSERT` operation for just one `NIAC`, using 3 procedures(2 for inserting into tables, and 1 to call both procedures and to insert into another table all the ID's of the tables where data was inserted, so all the data would be linked to a NIAC).

The script for inserting data into table is bellow:
1 procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertXMLMultipleTables]
(
@idAddress1 int out,
@idAddress2 int out,
@idactivities int out,
@idgoods int out,
@idmobileunit int out,
@idcommercial int out,
@idcommercialut int out,
@idpsu int out,
@idmerchant int out,
@xml xml
)
as 
set @xml = *


begin 
set nocount on

INSERT INTO Activities(Code,Name)
        SELECT  
    
Code=c.value('Code[1]','nvarchar(90)') ,
Name=c.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(90)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Activities/Activity') Activities(c)
set @IDActivities=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
end;




begin
INSERT INTO Address(Region,Locality,Street,House,Block,Flat,Phone,Fax,Email)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('Region[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Locality=c.value('Locality[1],','nvarchar(50)') ,
        Street=c.value('Street[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        House=c.value('House[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Block=c.value('Block[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Flat=c.value('Flat[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Phone=c.value('Phone[1],','nvarchar(30)') ,
        Fax=c.value('Fax[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        Email=c.value('Email[1],','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Merchant/Address') Address(c)
    set @idAddress1=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO Merchant(IDNX,Name,WorkProgram,IdAddress)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('IDNx[1],','nvarchar(max)'),
        Locality=c.value('Name[1],','nvarchar(max)') ,
        Street=c.value('WorkProgram[1],','datetime2') ,
        @idAddress1
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Merchant') Merchant(c)
    set @idmerchant=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    
begin
INSERT INTO Address(Region,Locality,Street,House,Block,Flat,Phone,Fax,Email)
        SELECT 
        Region=c.value('Region[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Locality=c.value('Locality[1],','nvarchar(50)') ,
        Street=c.value('Street[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        House=c.value('House[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Block=c.value('Block[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Flat=c.value('Flat[1],','nvarchar(10)') ,
        Phone=c.value('Phone[1],','nvarchar(30)') ,
        Fax=c.value('Fax[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        Email=c.value('Email[1],','nvarchar(60)')   
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Address') Address(c)
    set @idAddress2=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    set @idcommercialut=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    end;


    begin
    INSERT INTO CommercialApparatus(Count,Length,Width,Height )
        SELECT      
    Count =c.value('Type[1]','int') ,
        Length=c.value('Length[1]','int') ,
         Width=c.value('Width[1]','int') ,
         Height=c.value('Height[1]','int') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/CommercialApparatus') CommercialApparatus(c)
    set @idcommercial=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;




    begin
    INSERT INTO Goods(Name)
        SELECT 
        Name=c.value('Name[1]','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/Goods/Good') Goods(c)
    set @idgoods=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO MobileUnit(Type,Length,Width,Height )
        SELECT  
    Type =c.value('Type[1]','int') ,
        Length=c.value('Length[1]','int') ,
         Width=c.value('Width[1]','int') ,
         Height=c.value('Height[1]','int') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/MobileUnit') MobileUnit(c)
         set @idmobileunit=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;



    begin
    INSERT INTO PublicSupplyUnit(Capacity,TerraceCapacity)
        SELECT 
        Capacity=c.value('Capacity[1]','int') ,
        TerraceCapacity=c.value('TerraceCapacity[1]','int')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit/PublicSupplyUnit') PublicSupplyUnit(c)
    set @idpsu=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;



    begin
    INSERT INTO CommercialUnit(IDNX,Name,Type,Area,Location,TerraceCapacity,TradingAlcohol,TradingBeer,TradingTobaccoProducts,AmbulatoryTrading,MobileUnitTrading,CommercialApparatusTrading,IDActivities,IdAddress,IDCommercial,IDGoods,IDMobileUnit,IDPSU)
        SELECT 
        IDNx=c.value('IDNx[1],','nvarchar(90)'),
        Name=c.value('Name[1],','nvarchar(90)') ,
        Type=c.value('Type[1],','nvarchar(90)') ,
        Area=c.value('Area[1],','int') ,
        Location=c.value('Location[1],','nvarchar(max)'),
        TerraceCapacity=c.value('TerraceCapacity[1],','float') ,
        TradingAlcohol=c.value('TradingAlcohol[1],','bit') ,
        TradingBeer=c.value('TradingBeer[1],','bit') ,
        TradingTobaccoProducts=c.value('TradingTobaccoProducts[1],','bit'),
        AmbulatoryTrading=c.value('AmbulatoryTrading[1],','bit') ,
        MobileUnitTrading=c.value('MobileUnitTrading[1],','bit') ,
        CommercialApparatusTrading=c.value('CommercialApparatusTrading[1],','bit') ,
        @idactivities,@idAddress2,@idcommercial,@idgoods,@idmobileunit,@idpsu
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/CommercialUnit') CommercialUnit(c)
    end;
```

2 procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertXMLNIAC]
(
@xml xml,
@idNIAC int output,
@idCessation int output
)
as 
set @xml=*

begin 
set nocount on


INSERT INTO NIAC(Number,SubmissionDate,ExpirationDate,IssuerIDNO,IssuerName,SuspensionPeriod,Modifications)
        SELECT 
        Number=c.value('Number[1],','nvarchar(80)'),
        SubmissionDate=c.value('SubmissionDate[1],','datetime2') ,
        ExpirationDate=c.value('ExpirationDate[1],','datetime2') ,
        IssuerIDNO=c.value('IssuerIDNO[1],','nvarchar(max)') ,
        IssuerName=c.value('IssuerName[1],','nvarchar(60)') ,
        SuspensionPeriod=c.value('SuspensionPeriod[1],','datetime2') ,
        Modifications=c.value('Modifications[1],','nvarchar(60)') 
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC') NIAC(c)
    set @idNIAC=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;

    begin
    INSERT INTO Cessation(Basis,Date,IDNIAC)
        SELECT 
        Basis=c.value('Basis[1],','nvarchar(60)'),
        Date=c.value('Date[1],','date') ,      
        @idNIAC
    FROM @xml.nodes('NIACList/NIAC/Cessation') Cessation(c)
    set @idCessation=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end;
```

3 procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NIACFORCOMPONENTS]
@xml1 xml
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
        @idAddress1 int,
        @idAddress2 int,
        @idactivities int,
        @idgoods int,
        @idmobileunit int,
        @idcommercial int,
        @idcommercialut int,
        @idpsu int,
        @idmerchant int,
        @idNIAC int,
        @idCessation int


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount=@@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXEC [dbo].[InsertXMLMultipleTables]
        @idAddress1 = @idAddress1 OUTPUT,
        @idAddress2 = @idAddress2 OUTPUT,
        @IDActivities = @idactivities OUTPUT,
        @idgoods = @idgoods OUTPUT,
        @idmobileunit = @idmobileunit OUTPUT,
        @idcommercial = @idcommercial OUTPUT,
        @idcommercialut = @idcommercialut OUTPUT,
        @idpsu = @idpsu OUTPUT,
        @idmerchant = @idmerchant OUTPUT,
        @xml = @xml1


        EXEC [dbo].[InsertXMLNIAC]
        
        @idNIAC = @idNIAC OUTPUT,
        @idCessation = @idCessation OUTPUT,
        @xml=@xml1

     
        


         begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction NIACFORCOMPONENTS;

        

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                 @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction NIACFORCOMPONENTS;

        raiserror ('NIACFORCOMPONENTS: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
        return;
    end catch   
    
    Begin
                              
        INSERT INTO NIACToComponents(IDNIAC,IdCessation,IdMerchant,IDAddressMerchant,IDAddressCU,IDCommercialUt,IDActivities,IDGoods,IDMobileUnit,IDCommercial,IDPSU)
        SELECT 
        @idNIAC as N'@idNIAC',
        @idCessation as N'@idCessation',
        @idmerchant as N'@idmerchant',
        @idAddress1 as N'@idAddress1',
        @idAddress2 as N'@idAddress2',
        @idcommercialut as N'@idcommercialut',
        @idactivities as N'@idactivities',
        @idgoods as N'@idgoods',
        @idmobileunit as N'@idmobileunit',
        @idcommercial as N'@idcommercial',
        @idpsu as N'@idpsu'
        
        
    
    COMMIT
        END             
END
```

Based on these scripts, the insert works perfectly for one `NIAC`, every ID from the table is linked to it, but i want to do such insert to all the `NIAC` nodes inside the `NIACList`, knowing the position to each of them.

Comment: I would recommend to perform the XML reading and DB inserting via SSIS. It works quite fine, especially when you create a XSLT sheet which does the XML interpretation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following conceptual example for your needs.

You can `INSERT` data into a DB table by iterating through the parent XML elements. You would need two INSERT statements. Right after the first of them, you would need to preserve an IDENTITY value like you are already doing it today, to be used in the 2nd INSERT for child XML fragments and corresponding rows.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @INPUTXML XML = '<Lineitems>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Net Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>TRIN</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>
  </Lineitem>
  <Lineitem>
    <Ticker>TER</Ticker>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LineItem>Cost of Revenue</LineItem>
    <XFundCode>XXP</XFundCode>
    <UserID>TDP</UserID>    
  </Lineitem>
</Lineitems>';

DECLARE @Ticker  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
   , @ID        AS INT
   , @Lineitem  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
   , @XFundCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)
   , @UserID    AS VARCHAR(MAX);

-- count total number of items
DECLARE @i INT
   , @cnt INT = @INPUTXML.value('count(/Lineitems/Lineitem)', 'INT');
SELECT @cnt;

-- loop XML item by item
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= @cnt BEGIN

      SELECT @Ticker = col.value('(Ticker/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
         , @ID = col.value('(ID/text())[1]','INT')
         , @Lineitem = col.value('(LineItem/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
         , @XFundCode = col.value('(XFundCode/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
         , @UserID = col.value('(UserID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
      FROM @INPUTXML.nodes('/Lineitems/Lineitem[position() = sql:variable("@i")]') AS tab(col)

     -- do whatever needed in the loop here

   SET @i += 1;
END
```

Comment: markossw, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.